# qt5_wrap_cpp() not generating cpp file although it claims it does

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am having issues with `qt5_wrap_cpp` on windows only. I have the same code on Linux and everything works fine.

Here's a snippet of what I do:

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(QtWrapMocSourceList "Misc/QSignalBridge.h;Signal/DeferredSignal.h;Widget/ClickableLabel.h")
message(STATUS "QtWrapMocSourceList = ${QtWrapMocSourceList}")
```

Output of this is:

```
gQtWrapMocSourceList = C:/work/project/build/ui/coreui/Misc/moc_QSignalBridge.cpp;C:/work/project/build/ui/coreui/Signal/moc_DeferredSignal.cpp;C:/work/project/build/ui/coreui/Widget/moc_ClickableLabel.cpp
```

According to the ouput variable from `qt5_wrap_cpp`, the called work. However, when I go to said folders, I only get:

```
build/ui/coreui/Signal/moc_DeferredSignal.cpp_parameters
build/ui/coreui/Misc/moc_QSignalBridge.cpp_parameters
build/ui/coreui/Widget/moc_ClickableLabel.cpp_parameters
```

What could be causing this? I have the same code on Linux and Windows and only Windows fails.

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to reproduce this issue please privde 
a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Also note that the files might be generated at the build phase.

Comment: Why don't you use the [`AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) instead?

Comment: @teivaz Apologies. I just found out what the issue is.  I am also using Cotire and am using CMake 3.13.3. Apparently, from CMake 3.12.0 onwards, Cotire causes isses when using `moc` files. There doesn't appear to be any fix out yet,

Comment: @teivaz I personnally would prefer to avoid `AUTOMOC` as our project doesn't use that many `moc` files and it adds more time to the process.

Comment: the AUTOMOC can be set to a single target. So if you have only few targets that need moc this would help.